# value saveAsTextFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(String, Long)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am try to save my wordcount result in file.

```
val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordCounts.saveAsTextFile("/home/hadoop/datafile1")
```

But it is showing

```
value saveAsTextFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(String, Long)]              [error]     wordCounts.saveAsTextFile("/home/hadoop/datafile1")
```

I am using spark 2.1. I show  one answer which is suggesting old spark version.But I want to do in spark 2.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a method defined for `RDD` on a `DStream`.

This is the method on `RDD`:

```
def saveAsTextFile(path: String): Unit
```

...with description "*Save this RDD as a text file, using string representations of elements*."

This is the method on `DStream`:

```
saveAsTextFiles(prefix: String, suffix: String = ""): Unit
```

...with description "*Save each RDD in this DStream as at text file, using string representation of elements. The file name at each batch interval is generated based on prefix and suffix: "prefix-TIME_IN_MS.suffix.*"

So the method signatures are different--both in name and parameters.

In your code, `wordCounts` is apparently a `DStream`, so it does not have a `saveAsTextFile` method.

However, I get the feeling you are confusing the abstractions and really want to write the individual `RDD`s contained in a `DStream` microbatch. To do that:

```
counts.foreachRDD { rdd => 
  ...         
  rdd.saveAsTextFiles(s"/home/hadoop/datafile-$timestamp")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.html) mentions the API as "saveAsTextFiles"

```
saveAsTextFiles(String prefix, String suffix)
```

> Save each RDD in this DStream as at text file, using string
>   representation of elements.